# Cross database access doesn't work on Windows group?

Tags: sql-server

I've created a Windows group `domain\group` and added Windows user `domain\user1` to the group. Then create login

```
use master
create login [domain\group] for windows 
use myDB
create user [domain\group] for login [domain\group]
grant select on schema::mySchema to [domain\group]
```

I enabled cross database access

```
use master
EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced', 1;
RECONFIGURE with override;
EXECUTE sp_configure 'cross db ownership chaining', 1;
RECONFIGURE with override;
```

The following statement works.

```
exec ('select 1 a') as login = 'domain\user'
```

However, I got the following error when selecting a view accessing a table in another database.

```
create view mySchema.view1 as select * from anotherDb.dbo.table1
go
exec ('select * from mySchema.view1') as login = 'domain\user'
```

`Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
The server principal "domain\user1" is not able to access the database "anotherDb" under the current security context.`

Comment: Did you make domain\group a user in anotherDb?

Comment: Just added `use anotherDb; create user [domain\group] for login [domain\group]`. Still got the error for user1

Answer (score 1):

According to this MSDN article, if you are using dynamic SQL then the user must exist in both databases (or if a procedure is signed by a cert that exists in both databases). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669059(v=vs.110).aspx

> Cross-database ownership chaining does not work in cases where
>   dynamically created SQL statements are executed unless the same user
>   exists in both databases. You can work around this in SQL Server by
>   creating a stored procedure that accesses data in another database and
>   signing the procedure with a certificate that exists in both
>   databases. This gives users access to the database resources used by
>   the procedure without granting them database access or permissions.

Make sure the databases have the same owner:

```
select d.name, d.owner_sid, owner_name = suser_sname(d.owner_sid) 
from sys.databases d 
where d.name in ('myDB','anotherDB')
```

Also check that the database objects in each database have the same owner_login (and owner_login should not be `NULL`) using the query below, or else the ownership chain would be broken:

```
use myDB
go

select o.name, o.type_desc
    , owner_name = USER_NAME(OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id, 'OwnerId'))
    , owner_login = suser_sname(p.sid)
from sys.objects o 
left join sys.database_principals p on p.principal_id = OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id, 'OwnerId') 
where o.name = 'view1'
and o.schema_id = schema_id('mySchema')
go

use anotherDB
go

select o.name, o.type_desc
    , owner_name = USER_NAME(OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id, 'OwnerId'))
    , owner_login = suser_sname(p.sid)
from sys.objects o 
left join sys.database_principals p on p.principal_id = OBJECTPROPERTY(o.object_id, 'OwnerId') 
where o.name = 'table1'
and o.schema_id = schema_id('dbo')
go
```

Comment: I added the `domain\group` to anotherDb but still got the error. I use dynamic SQL only for testing unser `domain\user1`'s credential.

Comment: Did you grant `domain\group` permission to `select` from `anotherDb.dbo.table1` as well?

Comment: It is also possible to configure the database owner chaining at the database level.  What are the results of this query for your 2 databases? `select d.name, d.is_db_chaining_on, d.is_trustworthy_on  from sys.databases d where d.name in ('myDB','anotherDB')`

Comment: I didn't grant the group to select anotherDb. The purpose of using cross-database chaining is I don't need to grant the permission on other databases.

Comment: The result of the query is `anotherDb: 0 0
currentdb: 1 0`

Comment: Do the databases have the same owner?  `select d.name, d.owner_sid, owner_name = suser_sname(d.owner_sid)
from sys.databases d 
where d.name in ('myDB','anotherDB')`

Comment: Yes, they have the same owner.

Comment: OK can you check the owner of each object as well using the query in the updated answer?

Comment: Yes, the two objects have the same owner_login.